# What's debugTracking for in Omniture JS tracking?

Tags: adobe-analytics

We're about to start using Omniture, and have been provided with some JS.  It has this line in it:

```
s.debugTracking = true;
```

There's not much in the documentation about what this is.  Can anyone enlighten me?  Is it something you would want to set to false on production?  Is it necessary to make plugins like [Omnibug](http://omnibug.rosssimpson.com/) work?

I found these references in Adobe's documentation, none of which really explain what it's for:

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/video/video_flash_test.html

```
/* Turn on and configure debugging here */
s.debugTracking = true;
```

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/release/c_release_notes_javascript.html

```
Added debugTracking flag to enable logging of requests send to Firebug console just like the other platforms.
```

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/video/video_flash_sample.html

```
/* Turn on and configure debugging here - turn this off for production deployment */
s.debugTracking = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debugTracking` essentially just sends a `console.log` call of the request that was made and breaks out all of the parameters. It isn't required for tools like Omnibug or DigitalPulse debugger to work.

It can be removed, or set to false to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like having that set to true causes a lot of relevant information to then be sent automatically to the console, in a section labelled `AppMeasurement Debug`.  Starting with the tracking domain, current URL and the key-value pairs of data being logged.

Given Omnibug and other plugins allow us to see this stuff anyway, we can just remove the `s.debugTracking` line.